# supermicro motherboard, X10SRA-F-O , no beep no display

Tags: bios, supermicro

Motherboard is X10SRA-F-O

Cpu:Intel Xeon E5-1620V4

Graphics:Quadro P4000 + Radeon Pro WX7100

I installed a fresh windows 10 and then I was updating my drivers using the Driver Booster (from IOBIT.com).

After shutdown the system never started up , no display, no beep and no initial boot menu.

The LED on the motherboard just shows 00 and no beep (see the attached picture please)
[image]

I disconnected everything (graphic cards, hard drives, CD drive) and used the onboard VGA , still no display. I also made sure the JPG1 pin is connected to pin 1-2 so the onboard VGA is enable as you can see in the picture.
[image]

I changed the CMOS battery, rest the CMOS using the small button (CLR_CMOS_SW) and still nothing happening.

I tried to restore the bios using the recovery method in the manual:

1- I copied the proper bios file to a USB, remained it to super.rom

2- Moved the JBRI, pressed the S11

but nothing happened.

I dont know what is wrong
I also notices when I connect the keyboard to USB the Capslock light doesn't not go on and off

why should a simple update destroy the whole system?

dose anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Many thanks

Comment: strip the memory and check what's going on, if its not doing anything 2 options left: cpu or mb is faulty

Comment: I removed the memory and still no beep and I get a constant 00 on the motherboard LED

Comment: und what boot code do you get without cpu? have you maybe a other cpu that fits in the socket? additionally maybe this helps you there are multiple jumpers for recovery https://support.dvsus.com/hc/en-us/article_attachments/207474426/Produto28318IdArquivo3087.pdf